# Collection of Subroutines or Dynamic Reference to Sub in C#

Tags: c#, excel, controls, vsto

I'm working with a VSTO, that uses a whole lot of buttons on a work sheet.  I had problems with the ActiveX controls going missing if I tried to just have them stored in the workbook.  To fix that, I'm making all the buttons at runtime.  Not supper elegant, but I have function to help me with that:

```
public object MakeOButton(double LL, double TT, string ButtonName, params object[] ActionArray)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Controls.Button ButtonXX = new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Controls.Button();
    string ActionCall = ButtonName + "_Click";
    ButtonXX = this.Controls.AddButton(LL, TT, 18.75, 14.25, ButtonName);
    ButtonXX.Click += Interaction.CallByName(this, ActionCall, CallType.Method, ActionArray);
    return ButtonXX;
}
```

I then call this for all the buttons I want to make, and it drops in the right place and names them accordingly.  What I'm having trouble with is setting each one of these buttons to the correct click interaction.

Each button should be handled by a different routine which has the name `[ButtonName]_Click`.  I was hoping to not have to declare each button before hand, especially if I want to be dynamically changing which buttons are called.

To do that I need find some way to refer to the subroutine associated with the button dynamically.  At the moment, the only way I can think I might have chance is using the string `ButtonName_Click` to refer to the subroutine.  My thought was ether through a collection of all the subs that are in the worksheet, or to be able to refer to it directly.

My best idea (which is in the above code) successfully calls the sub dynamically, but doesn't set the interaction to the click, it just make's it click at creation:

```
ButtonXX.Click += Interaction.CallByName(this, ActionCall, CallType.Method, ActionArray);
```

I feel like I must be so close to the right answer.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `Interaction.CallByName` method is actually invoking the method immediately.  What you need to do is set it up so that it's called when the `Click` occurs.  The easiest way to do that is to use an anonymous method

```
ButtonXX.Click += delegate { 
  Interaction.CallByName(this, ActionCall, CallType.Method, ActionArray); 
};
```

This creates a method that will be called when the `Click` event happens.  At that time the body of the method will run and execute `Interaction.CallByName`

Comment: Unless I'm messing up, this seems to still be calling at the creation, but thanks for the lead.

Comment: @AtlLED it should only be calling it at creation time if the `Click` event is happening at creation too.  Have you tried putting a break point in the delegate body and seeing what the call stack is when it gets invoked?

Comment: Yep.  It and it's right here at this line. I'm now curious if this is because of `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Controls`

Comment: So you got me to the solution: `ButtonXX.Click += Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(System.EventHandler), this, ActionCall, true);` If you want to edit your answer with this I'll accept.